# Get altering queries in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a large test suite which restores the whole MongoDB database after each test, which works kinda like Rails fixtures. This suite contains also a lot of readonly tests, so I'm doing unnecessary restores and this eats up the performance. Marking these tests somehow would work, but I tend to forget it and it is more cumbersome then helpful. However I could increase the performance drastically by running the restoring process (mongodump and mongorestore) only if some altering operations have been done. So my question is:

Is there any way to get all the (altering) Mongoid queries (or at least the count) which were performed since a particular point in time? Maybe from the log, maybe Mongoid has some internal counter…

Comment: Moped (the underlying MongoDB access library that Mongoid uses) can do some fairly verbose logging options, you might be able to turn up the noise and parse the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB's command `serverStatus` returns the number of operations done, so I can hook them up pretty easily:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @opcounters = opcounters
  end

  teardown do
    if opcounters != @opcounters
      system "mongorestore --drop #{File.expand_path('../tmp',  __FILE__)} > /dev/null 2>&1"
    end
  end

private
  def opcounters
    Mongoid::Sessions.default.command(serverStatus: 1).fetch('opcounters').slice('insert', 'update', 'delete')
  end
end
```

Btw this increased the performance of my tests by more than 50%.